# Write a function that reduces compositions of linear operators

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming

You are given two functions \$g(x)\$ and \$h(x)\$, each of which takes an integer \$x\$ and returns the number \$ax + b\$ (where \$a\$ and \$b\$ are integers defined in the function).

Your task is to write a function \$f(g, h)\$ that takes these two functions, and returns a function \$k(x) = g(h(x))\$, but where the procedure of \$k(x)\$ is also simply of the form \$ax + b\$.

For example, given \$g(x) = 2x + 3\$ and \$h(x) = 3x + 4\$, you would need to return \$k(x) = 6x + 11\$, and not \$k(x) = 2(3x + 4) + 3\$.

Comment: Yes. There is a way to extract those two constants without accessing the AST.

Comment: May I suggest clarifying that the return value is of function type as well, as I'm guessing is your intent? Two of the current answers return strings.

Comment: @KevinReid Done.

Comment: I'm thinking of rewarding a bounty for an answer in binary lambda calculus...

Comment: I don't understand how you want the output. If it's as a function, you could just black-box compose the inputs. Do you want the pair `(a,b)` for which `k(x)=ax+b`? A function that must be written in the form `k(x)=ax+b`? If the second, do `a` and `b` have to be given explicit assignments in that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>41</strike> <strike>40</strike> <strike>23</strike> 19 characters

```
{2,0+%/-{@*+}++}:k;
```

Thanks to Peter Taylor for pointing out this solution. Accepts two function bodies as arguments.

The following examples show how to use function `k`:

```
# As function
{2*3+} {3*4+} k         # => {11 6 @*+}

# Apply to value
5 {2*3+} {3*4+} k ~     # => 41
```

If one wants to retain the original output format, the following 22 character solution is possible:

```
{2,0+%/-{*}+\+{+}+}:k;

{2*3+} {3*4+} k         # => {6 * 11 +}
```

Explanation of the code:

```
{                       # on stack are functions g h
  2,                    # build array [0 1] -> g h [0 1]
  0+                    # append 0 -> g h [0 1 0]
  %                     # apply function h to each element -> g [h(0) h(1) h(0)]
  /                     # apply function g to each element
                        # and break up the array -> g(h(0)) g(h(1)) g(h(0))
  -                     # subtract last two -> g(h(0)) g(h(1))-g(h(0))
  {@*+}++               # append function body to these values
}:k;                    # save function to variable k
```

Comment: Save 4: `{2,%/1$-{@*+}++}:k;` or `{2,0+%/-{@*+}++}:k;`

Comment: Your explanation makes me never want to learn Golfscript. It would make my head explode trying to figure it out.

Comment: @jdstankosky Do you mean the explanation is not clear (in which case I'd be happy to amend if you could point out what is unclear) or that GolfScript is - well - special (in which case you'll miss a lot of fun).

Comment: @Howard It's definitely interesting, incredibly confusing, and far more advanced than anything I think I'll ever be able to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 15

**Define g, h as pure functions**

`g` and `h` are defined as pure functions (awaiting a value or independent variable to be assigned)

```
g = 2 # + 3 &;
h = 3 # + 4 &;
g[x]
h[x]
```

> 3 + 2 x
> 4 + 3 x

---

**Method #1: Compose `g` of `h` directly** (15 chars)

```
g@h@x//Simplify
```

> 11 + 6 x

Or, alternatively: (17 chars)

```
g[h[x]]//Simplify
```

---

**Method #2: Define `f`** (25 chars= 13 + 10 chars for Simplify)

```
f=Composition
```

[image: composition]

```
f[g, h][x]
f[g, h][x] // Simplify
Composition[g, h][x]//Simplify
f[g, h][1]
Table[f[g, h][x], {x, 1, 13}]
```

> 3 + 2 (4 + 3 x)
> 11 + 6 x
> 11 + 6 x
> 17
> {17, 23, 29, 35, 41, 47, 53, 59, 65, 71, 77, 83, 89}

Comment: Your `f(g, h, x)` should be `f(g, h)(x)`.

Comment: Ok. I'll adjust accordingly

Answer (score 2):

#### Haskell, 31

```
(f%g)x=f(g 0)+x*(f(g 1)-f(g 0))
```

Version in which the function body contains only variables (equivalent at run time, but closer to the question's form), 38 characters:

```
(f%g)x=a*x+b where h=f.g;b=h 0;a=h 1-b
```

Note that in both cases, since Haskell uses curried functions, there is no explicit construction of the composed function as it is implicit in `%` being defined with three arguments: function f, function g, value x.

Example use:

```
> ((\x -> 2*x + 3)%(\x -> 3*x + 4)) 0
11
> ((\x -> 2*x + 3)%(\x -> 3*x + 4)) 4
35
```

Ungolfed second form:

```
(f % g) x = a * x + b        -- equivalent: (f % g) = \x -> a * x + b
  where
    h = f . g                -- use built in function composition to bootstrap
    b = h 0                  -- constant term of composed function
    a = h 1 - h 0            -- linear term of composed function
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `f%g=f(g 0)!(f(g 1-g 0)-f 0);(z!y)x=y*x+z` (40 chars) by replacing the `where` clause with a function call (which also gets rid of the lambda) and defining infix operators instead of plain functions. Also, I'm not sure if it's necessary to share the values of `y` and `z`, so you may be able to improve it further by inlining them as well.

Comment: @hammar I have my doubts that putting the expressions inline is in the spirit of the question (“the procedure of `k(x)` is also simply of the form `ax + b`”) but OK, I'll take the edit, unless Joe Zeng disagrees.

Comment: Either way, `f(g 1)-f(g 0)` is one char shorter than `f(g 1-g 0)-f 0`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point! In fact, that made me realize I was missing a trick in the original version: I now define `h = f . g` and derive all results from `h`, saving another two characters — I was previously stuck on the notion of extracting the coefficients of each function individually.

Answer (score 1):

### vba, 89

```
Function f(g,h,x)
f=Evaluate(Replace(g,"x","*("&Replace(h,"x","*"&x)&")"))  
End Function
```

usage/result

> ?f("2x+3","3x+4",1)
>    17

Comment: The functions aren't supposed to be strings. Can you evaluate the string directly with a number and get the result of the function out?

Comment: @JoeZeng, I think that is more what you were after

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 87

```
function f(g, h)local a,b=g(h(1))-g(h(0)),g(h(0))return function(x)return a*x+b end end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby >=1.9, 55

```
f=->g,h{a=(g[1]-g[0])*(h[1]-h[0]);b=g[h[0]];->x{a*x+b}}
```

Less golfed:

```
def c(f,g)
  f_a=f[1]-f[0]
  g_a=g[1]-g[0]
  a=f_a*g_a
  b=f[g[0]]
  ->x{a*x+b}
end
```

Comment: You can shorten even further by inlining `a`: `f=->g,h{->x{(g[h[1]]-b=g[h[0]])*x+b}}`

Comment: I wasn't sure that'd be permitted.

Answer (score 1):

### SML (60 chars)

```
fun f g h=let val c=g(h 0)val m=g(h 1)-c in fn x=>m*x+c end;
```

Ungolfed:

```
fun f g h =
    let val c = g (h 0)
        val m = g (h 1) - c
     in fn x => m*x + c
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> 13 bytes

```
vØ.v@µI,Ḣż⁾×+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//dsOYLnZAwrVJLOG4osW84oG@w5cr/8On//8iM8OXNCsi/yIyw5czKyI)

I think I understand what the question is asking for, but it really isn't clear exactly *how* the program is supposed to return \$a\$ and \$b\$, and it seems as though (given the [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) tag) that this is an unobservable requirement)

<s>11 bytes sacrificed to clumsy I/O formats.</s>

-9 bytes thanks to [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard)'s [method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11117/66833)

This takes \$g\$ and \$h\$ in Jelly's most natural form for non-black-box functions, as a string representing a Jelly link. As \$g(x)=ax+b\$ (and similar for \$h\$), this is equivalent to `a×b+`. We also return \$k\$ in the form `a×b+`. If this can instead take input and output as two lists `[a, b]` representing \$g\$ and \$h\$, we can reduce this to [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//w5figqzhuKIrMsKm4bmqe////1syLCAzXf9bMywgNF0).

### How it works

```
vØ.v@µI,Ḣż⁾×+ - Main link. Takes h ("c×d+") on the left and g ("a×b+") on the right
 Ø.           - [0, 1]
v             - Run h over each; [h(0), h(1)]
   v@         - Run g over each; [g(h(0)), g(h(1))]
     µ        - New link. Call this pair l and use it as the argument
      I       - Differences; g(h(0)) - g(h(1))
        Ḣ     - Head; g(h(0))
       ,      - Pair; [g(h(0)) - g(h(1)), g(h(0))]
          ⁾×+ - Yield "×+"
         ż    - Zip together; [g(h(0)) - g(h(1)), "×", g(h(0)), "+"]
                Implicitly smash together and print
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 72

Apparently I completely missed the point of this code-golf. I'm STILL not sure if I understand it correctly. Is no output required? Can I assume the methods of g and h? Here's a new version based off the old one:

```
<?=$f=function($g,$h,$x){return$k=($g[0]*$h[0]*$x)+($g[0]*$h[1])+$g[1];}
```

If this is still wrong, I give up.

---

## PHP 176

The requirements are kind of confusing, but here's what I think you meant:

```
<?=f($argv);function f($a){$x=$a[3];$g=explode("x",$a[1]);$h=explode("x",$a[2]);return$k=($g[0]*$h[0])."*$x+".(($g[0]*$h[1])+$g[1])."=".(($g[0]*$h[0]*$x)+($g[0]*$h[1])+$g[1]);}
```

Usage: `php f.php 2x+3 3x+4 5`

Output: `6*5+11=41`

Another Example

Usage: `php f.php 4x-7 3x+4 2`

Output: `12*2+9=33`

## Method

As you described, we can't simply output the answer with `g(h(x))`, we had to create function `f(g,h)` which determines what both the functions would be **together,** and return that as a new function: `k(x)`.

Is this what OP meant?

**Ungolfed**

```
<?php

function f($a) {
    $x=$a[3];
    $g=explode("x",$a[1]);
    $h=explode("x",$a[2]);
    $k  = $g[0]*$h[0];
    $k .= "*";
    $k .= $x;
    $k .= "+";
    $k .= ($g[0]*$h[1])+$g[1];
    $k .= " = ";
    $k .= ($g[0]*$h[0]*$x) + ($g[0]*$h[1])+$g[1];
    return $k;
}

echo f($argv);
```

Comment: In PHP terminology, the requirements are asking for a function which takes two callbacks as arguments and returns a callback. As an implementation note, I would expect to see a couple of calls to `call_user_func` and probably a call to `create_function`.

Answer (score 0):

**Erlang 54:**

```
1> F = fun(G,H)->B=G(H(0)),A=G(H(1))-B,fun(X)->A*X+B end end.
2> (F(fun(X) -> 2*X+3 end, fun(X) -> 3*X + 4 end))(0).
11
3> (F(fun(X) -> 2*X+3 end, fun(X) -> 3*X + 4 end))(1) - v(2).
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp (108)

```
(defun f(g h)(let*((d(g 0))(c(-(g 1)d))(z(h 0))(e(-(h 1)z))(a(* c e))(b(+(* c z)d)))(lambda(x)(+(* a x)b))))
```

It could be shorter if I assumed expressions would have constants folded...but I didn't make that assumption to make sure I met the spec.  Also, I have implemented Clojure's literal anonymous function syntax as a read macro.  I decided against using that as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Postscript, 120

```
/f{1 index 0 get dup 
2 index 0 get mul exch
3 2 roll 2 get mul 
3 2 roll 2 get add[3 1 roll/mul cvx exch/add cvx]cvx}def
```

Ungolfed and commented with testing.

```
/g{2 mul 3 add}def
/h{3 mul 4 add}def

/f{
    1 index 0 get % g h g[0]
    dup 2 index 0 get mul % g h g[0] g[0]*h[0]
    exch 3 2 roll 2 get mul % g g[0]*h[0] g[0]*h[2]
    3 2 roll 2 get add % g[0]*h[0] g[0]*h[2]+g[2]
    [ 3 1 roll /mul cvx exch /add cvx ] cvx 
}def

//g //h f ==
```

Output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)
Copyright (C) 2013 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
{6 mul 11 add}
GS>
```